# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):

Tags: c#, windows, acrobat

Уважаемые гуру, прошу вашей помощи. При открытии файла .pdf получаю ошибку. Самое странное и интересное что ошибка только на одном компьютере из десяти при этом **Версия Net.Framework и adobe reader одинаковая на всех компьютерах**! Для открытия файла использую класс Process:

```
 Process.Start(str);
```

Текст ошибки:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): В
>   результате вызова компонента COM возвращена ошибка в формате HRESULT
>   E_FAIL.    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid,
>   Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid
>   clsid)    в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
>   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()

Подробная информация об использовании оперативной 
(JIT) отладки вместо данного диалогового 
окна содержится в конце этого сообщения.

```
************** Текст исключения **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): В результате вызова компонента COM возвращена ошибка в формате HRESULT E_FAIL.
   в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   в System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   в PrinterDocuments.PrintPreviewPDF.InitializeComponent()
   в PrinterDocuments.PrintPreviewPDF..ctor(String path)
   в PrinterDocuments.Form1.dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Загруженные сборки **************
mscorlib
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
PrinterDocuments
    Версия сборки: 1.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/medikovae/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/ZMRPWJLP.CP6/TWEZLY0H.5KT/prin..tion_5396d1b078ae3e53_0001.0000_2dbc2a3323b57c8c/PrinterDocuments.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34251 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34270 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34280 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.AcroPDFLib
    Версия сборки: 1.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/medikovae/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/ZMRPWJLP.CP6/TWEZLY0H.5KT/prin..tion_5396d1b078ae3e53_0001.0000_2dbc2a3323b57c8c/AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** Оперативная отладка (JIT) **************
Для подключения оперативной (JIT) отладки файл .config данного
приложения или компьютера (machine.config) должен иметь
значение jitDebugging, установленное в секции system.windows.forms.
Приложение также должно быть скомпилировано с включенной
отладкой.

Например:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

При включенной отладке JIT любое необрабатываемое исключение
пересылается отладчику JIT, зарегистрированному на данном компьютере,
вместо того чтобы обрабатываться данным диалоговым окном.
```

Comment: Ошибка не связана с `Process.Start`. Stack trace выглядит неполным, можно увидеть полный?

Comment: Какая битность операционной системы на тех компьютерах на которых работает, и на том, на котором не работает?

Comment: Windows 7  64 разрядная - все!

Comment: Эта ошибка показывает, что есть проблема с каким то ActiveX/COM компонентом используемым в программе. С запуском процесса она впрямую не связана. Какой ActiveX/COM программа пытается вызвать?

Comment: сейчас полный текст ошибки выложу. Извините, забыл написать сразу же

Comment: Из какой dll приходит `PrinterDocuments.PrintPreviewPDF` ?

Comment: Извините, забыл написать сразу. В программе используется AcroPDFLib  для просмотра файлов pdf и исключения именно при просмотре!!!

Comment: Воот. Нужно переустановить/перерегестрировать AcroPDFLib значит. Проблема в ней. Может не хватает какой то зависимости.

Comment: Переустановка библиотеки проблему не решила!!!!!!!!!!!!!! всё также на этом компьютере не работает, exception при просмотре

Comment: Сочувствую и желаю удачи =)

Comment: НЕ работает только на одном компьютере, что то с железом может быть?

Comment: Вот ещё, возможно релевантно: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796245/error-hresult-e-fail-with-acropdflib-component

Comment: Решил проблему!!! проблема была в профиле юзера!!!

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему!!! проблема была в профиле юзера!!!

Comment: Распишите решение более подробно, вдруг кто-то в будущем столкнётся с похожей проблемой?

Comment: да, тут особо и писать нечего, просто зашли на комп под другим пользователем и всё понятно стало

Comment: @Vlad а что именно было не так с профилем - не выяснили?

Comment: нет не выяснили, не знаю, просто профиль снести решили